# My button will not refresh to a new page with .live("click",function(){}); jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If I click or vclick my button anchor tag. The page will not load a new one. Here is my code. I am using the most up to date version of Jquery mobile. This problem started for me today.

Code:

```
 $("a[href=#Page1").live("click",function()
 {
       updateList();
      //Will show a list and I called $("#list").listview("refresh");
 }
```

HTML:

Page that has the link:

```
  <div data-role="page" id="Page2">
      <div data-role="header">
       <h3> Header </h3>
       </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <a role="button" href="#Page1"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Page transitioning to:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Page1">
    <div data-role="header">
       <h3> Header </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       <ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="true">
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing some code right there...

Comment: I really hope there's more code...

Comment: It would really help to post the complete line of code, and maybe the line above and below for context. but at least the complete line so we can see the anonymous function body.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? In 1.7, .live has been deprecated in favor of .on.

Comment: Version 1.2.0 RC2 for jQuery Mobile and 1.8.0 for jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure to get what you are trying to do, but here is some working code: (you were missing the `]` closing tag)

```
 $("a[href=#Page1]").live("click",function()
 {
       updateList();
      //Will show a list and I called listview.refresh();
 }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#Page1">Link</a>
[...]
<div data-role="page" id="Page1">
<div data-role="header">
  Header
</div>

</div>
```